# Exception using WebService client.(MyEclipse)

Tags: java, web-services, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I`am trying to generate web service client through MyEclipse, using my wsdl.

Ive got the auto-generated classes, and I got this auto-generated example:

/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI. JAX-WS RI 2.1.3-hudson-390-
 * Generated source version: 2.0
 *

* An example of how this class may be used:
 * 
 *

```
 * MibasBillingQueryNew service = new MibasBillingQueryNew();
 * MibasBillingQueryNewSoap portType = service.getMibasBillingQueryNewSoap();
 * portType.mibasBillingQuery(...);
 *
```

* 
 *

* 
 */

After I tried to follow this example, and adopt it to my code, I tried this:

```
        MibasBillingQueryNew service = new MibasBillingQueryNew();
```

MibasBillingQueryNewSoap portType =  service.getMibasBillingQueryNewSoap();

```
        String mibasResult=portType.mibasBillingQuery(password,
 parentProcessId, msg);
```

now after I tried to use this webservice account, this is the exception I get:

```
 javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: 
    Unhandled process exception
```

at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:188)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:116)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
 at $Proxy34.mibasBillingQuery(Unknown Source)
 at com.mirs.contentPackage.utils.MibasUtils.mibasRequestAdd(MibasUtils.java:132)
 at com.mirs.contentPackage.wap.PackageDisclaimerAck.execute(PackageDisclaimerAck.java:95)
 at com.mirs.contentPackage.wap.PackageDisclaimerAck.doGet(PackageDisclaimerAck.java:64)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Any idea?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, server didnt support jax, so i compiled client through Axis